# What happens when you can't move a piece on your turn

Tags: risk

Most of the times, I can't leave a terrirtory because it's being defended. Therefor I'm not able to move.

So, what happens when you can't move an army on your turn? Do you allow your opponent the next move?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have some misunderstanding of the rules, since the situation you describe can never occur (at least at the beginning of your turn). Whenever an enemy attacks one of your territories, the battle is always fully resolved immediately until either the attacker or defender has lost all their troops. Thus by the time your turn starts, every territory that still has any of your troops in it will NEVER have any enemy troops in it as well. Next, at the beginning of your turn, you always receive some reinforcements. Thus after placing reinforcements you will always have at least one territory which has more than a single troop in it. You are only required to leave one troop behind to 'defend' each territory, so at this point there are always some spare troops you can use to make at least one attack on your turn.

After one or more attacks, you may find that all your territories have only one troop left at which point yes you must end your turn.

Comment: You could put your reinforcements in territories that don't border any enemy troops. But I don't think you're obliged to make any attacks.